# How to parse the Pandas output to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing, floating-point

i'm using Pandas in python, and i'm trying to get only the value of this variable 'teste', but the pandas only return the entire thing. I just wanna the value like '0.0', how can i parse this value to float?

Current code:

```
teste = df.loc[df['NUMERO_DOC'].astype(str).astype(int) == 2, 'DOCS_RECEBIDOS_NUMERO']
teste.head()

Output:

0    0.0
Name: DOCS_RECEBIDOS_NUMERO, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `squeeze` to reduce the dimension:

- When you squeeze a `Dataframe` of 1 column, you transform it as a `Series`.
- When you squeeze a `Series` of 1 row, you transform it as a `scalar value`.

```
>>> df.loc[df['NUMERO_DOC'].astype(str).astype(int) == 2, 'DOCS_RECEBIDOS_NUMERO'].squeeze()
0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.iloc[0]` to the the first actual value of a Series:

```
>>> teste.head().iloc[0]
0.0
```